# Need to disable down key on my Laptop Keyboard

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard

I need to disable the down arrow key on my laptop. I have a windows 7 Gateway Quad Core laptop. On searching the internet I found similar questions of how to without any response beyond replace the key or get a usb keyboard and disable the laptop one.

Answer (score 1):

[KeyTweak](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/KeyTweak.shtml) is free software that allows you to disable/change keys. Once installed you can just disable <kbd>↓</kbd> and your good to go.